# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string in MS SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server

I am a newbie to MS SQL Server, I get the error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

running the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE DateVals 
(
    dt datetime,
    t time,
    dt2 datetime2,
    dts datetimeoffset
);
GO

INSERT INTO DateVals (dt, t, dt2, dts)
VALUES ('2011-01-01 23:10:10.003', '23:10:10.003', '2011-01-01 23:10:10.003', '2011-01-01 23:10:10.003 +02.00');
GO
```

Could you tell me why I get this error?

PS. My OS language is Polish

Answer (score 1):

Your query is correct, just need a colon instead of a comma in the datetimeoffset when you use +02:00.

```
INSERT INTO DateVals (dt, t, dt2, dts)
VALUES ('2011-01-01 23:10:10.003', '23:10:10.003', '2011-01-01 23:10:10.003', '2011-01-01 23:10:10.003 +02:00');
```

Instead of

```
INSERT INTO DateVals (dt, t, dt2, dts)
VALUES ('2011-01-01 23:10:10.003', '23:10:10.003', '2011-01-01 23:10:10.003', '2011-01-01 23:10:10.003 +02.00');
```

Answer (score 1):

Converting a string literal into a `DATETIME` column is quite an adventure - and `DATETIME` is *very peculiar* about what formats are supported.

The best way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

So in your case, try either:

```
INSERT INTO DateVals (dt, t, dt2, dts)
VALUES ('2011-01-01T23:10:10', '23:10:10.003', '2011-01-01 23:10:10.003', '2011-01-01 23:10:10.003 +02:00');
```

(*you also need to use a `:` in the `+02:00` moniker for the `DATETIMEOFFSET` - not a dot or comma*)

or make `dt` in your table a column of type `DATETIME2(n)` (instead of `DATETIME`).

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

The recommendation for SQL Server 2008 and newer is to use `DATE` if you only need the date portion, and `DATETIME2(n)` when you need both date and time. You should try to start phasing out the `DATETIME` datatype if ever possible